# Is there a clear way to test that a React component returns another custom component that is built?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, tdd

For example,

ComponentA.tsx:

```
const ComponentA = () => {
    return (
        <>
        <ComponentB/>
        </>
    )
}
```

ComponentA.test.tsx

```
describe("ComponentA", () => {
    it("Calls ComponentB in render", () => {
        render(<ComponentA/>);
        const componentB = <ComponentB/>;
        expect(componentB).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    });
});
```

Tried the above but the test still failed. I was hoping something similar to that would work, and I tried other variations of the above, but still didn't get to the passing test. There was once instance where I ran something similar to this with a waitFor around the expect and it passed, but the passing test wasn't correctly passing.

Answer (score 0):

[`toHaveBeenCalled(..)`](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#tohavebeencalled) works with mock functions.

To test that `ComponentA` is calling `ComponentB`, you create a mock `ComponentB` function and instantiate `<ComponentA/>`:

```js
const ComponentA = () => {
    return (
        <>
        <ComponentB/>
        </>
    )
}

// Create mock function
const ComponentB = jest.fn();

describe("ComponentA", () => {
    it("Calls ComponentB in render", () => {
        render(<ComponentA/>);
        expect(ComponentB).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Give ComponentB an `aria-label` then in your test get any element with that label and use `expect(element).toBeInTheDocument();` or something to that effect.

This is good practice for accessibility by the way. Because if elements are as supportive of accessibility as they should be, they should also have methods of easily identifying whether or not they are in the DOM. That's one of the purposes of the test case you are writing. Some lint rules can even be added to your environment to check for accessibility.